# generically detecting html position changes using jquery?

Tags: html, events, dom, detect

I'm using the excellent [BeautyTips plugin](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) as a means of indicating validation failures to end users and I'm running into positioning problems whenever page content is dynamically added, removed, or animated.

Here's a concrete example. I have a DIV at the top of each page that’s used for confirmation/error messages. It's displayed in $(document.ready) using  slideToggle(). This naturally "pushes" all subsequent html content down, throwing off the positioning/alignment of the beautytips.  If I call the plug-in's built-in refresh method after slideToggle() has fired, said positioning problems are corrected.   You can see the before/after screen-shots [here](http://img142.yfrog.com/img142/7808/afterslidetoggle.jpg)  and [here](http://img30.yfrog.com/img30/1728/aftermanuallyfixing.png).

One possible workaround would be to programmatically detect DOM changes, specifically changes to css, so that I could then loop over each beautytip and manually reload it. However, it appears that there are no native jQuery events which expose such functionality.  I've seen the impressive [jQuery plug-in by Rick  Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx) that monitors CSS changes, but it seems based on the assumption that one knows ahead of time the specific HTML element(s) they wish to monitor.  I want to monitor the entire document, since I can't be expected to know what html elements might exist on a given page that a) are going to be animated and b) would be at such a position in the document that they would "push" down the my beautytips.  And I certainly don't want to have to incur the massive performance penalty of polling every block level element in the document.

I should mention that the plug-in works perfectly if I use it in its default "hover" mode in which beautytips are displayed only in response to user mouse input.  Unfortunately, there is a design constraint imposed on the application that states all validation errors must be displayed after form submission without additional user interaction.

I'm sure there's a really simple/elegant fix that is completely eluding me.  I could avoid all of this hassle, of course, by simply not using animation to  display page content, but that seems like a high price to pay.

Comment: Have you evere found a solution to this problem? I'm having a similar issue where I read an element's offset values once at setup and would like to get informed if they should ever change, because I would need to update them in my buffer. However, it does not seem this is possible or am I wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never found a solution.